# How do I implicitly map folder views without breaking resource mappings?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am attempting to setup a very simple base configuration for a spring web application that can handle the following cases:

- map resource root requests to `/index`, eg `/` maps to `/index`, `/resource/` maps to `/resource/index`
- map `/static/**` to `/static/` (this is a resources view - css,js,images)
- handle some specific request paths with controller mappings
- map all other requests to a url based view, eg `/resource/page` maps to `/WEB-INF/views/resource/page.jsp`

In my current configuration what I have is:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
```

which works for static resources and root requests (`/`) but not for resource based root requests (`/resource/`). When attempting to handle all other requests (`**/`) I break handling of the static resources.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="**/*" />
```

Is there a way to do all of these things at the same time? It doesn't need to be an xml only solution, I'm fine with a code configuration or hybrid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution by implementing my own `Controller` and `Config`.

**view-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.view"/>
```

**com.example.web.view.ViewConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class ViewConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        vr.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return vr;
    }

    @Bean RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping(){
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Bean RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter(){
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setOrder(2); //process after mvc:resources
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

**com.example.web.view.ViewController**

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "**/")
    public String all(HttpServletRequest request) {     
        String path = request.getRequestURI().replace(request.getContextPath(),"");
        return path.endsWith("/") ? path +"index" : path;
    }

}
```

The magic was with setting the order value on the adaptor in `ViewConfig`. Spring creates a default mapping handler that all `RequestMapping`s found by component-scan are added to. The reason why my initial setup failed was that the ordering of this handler is to match before the one registered by `mvc:resources`. Creating my own adaptor and setting its order to be processed after `mvc:resources` allowed both to work.

Information regarding this can found in the spring documentation [19.9.1 Setting up the dispatcher for annotation support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html#portlet-annotation).

Of course the ViewConfig can also be implemented purely in xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web.view"/>
```

**Update:** Changed to `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` from `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` to reflect changes made in Spring 3.1.x and above.